# Swift Google map delegates are not working

Tags: swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a view containing a few google maps functions but for some odd reason the the "info window tapped " and "marker did tapped" doesn't do anything. Im not sure what Im missing. I have other extenstions in a few different files but i don't think that should cause any issues.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth
import CoreLocation
import GoogleMaps
import Font_Awesome_Swift


class DasboardVC: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate {

    //UnwindSegue
    @IBAction func unwindSegueDashboard(segue:UIStoryboardSegue){}

    //var sidebar items

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var addPhotoLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var showSideBar: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var hideMenuIcon: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var editProfileButon: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var message: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var settings: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var logout: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var sidebarView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var jobRequestSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var topBar: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var removePhoto: UIButton!


    let profileImageController = ProfileImageVC()
    let photoController = ProfilePicClass()


    //MapView Vars
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var didFindMyLocation = false
    var locationMarker: GMSMarker!


    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        sidebarView.hidden = true
        removePhoto.hidden = true
        topBar.backgroundColor = main()
        hideNavBar()
        sideBarMenuButton()

       // sidebarProfileImage()
       photoController.profileImage(profileImage, noImageLabel: addPhotoLabel)

    }
    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        showNavBar()
        viewloadedMap()

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        mapInset()

        mapView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "myLocation", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)

        mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true


        let ihelprCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.332052, -122.031088)


            ihelprLocation(ihelprCoordinate)


    }

    func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didTapInfoWindowOfMarker marker: GMSMarker) {
        print("infoWindowTapped")
    }

    func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
        print("markerTapped")

        return true
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `mapView.delegate = self` in the `viewDidLoad()` method

Comment: can u elaborate more on this? I tried loading my mapview in loadView and setting it to self.view = mapview but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

**For swift:**
    import UIKit
    import GoogleMaps

```
class DemoViewController: UIViewController, 
GMSMapViewDelegate {
}
```

When the GMSMapView is created, you can set its delegate to your view controller. The GMSMapViewDelegate provides only optional methods. To listen to any particular event, you must implement the relevant method.

```
override func loadView() {
  let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 1.285,
                                        longitude: 103.848,
                                        zoom: 12)

  let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: .zero, camera: camera)
  mapView.delegate = self
  self.view = mapView
}
```

// MARK: GMSMapViewDelegate

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
  print("You tapped at \(coordinate.latitude), \(coordinate.longitude)")
}
```